# Why is it necessary to take$\int \frac{1}{x}~ dx$, and split it into two pieces, left and right side? Lets say its bounded by $2$ and $-2$?

Tags: integration, divergent-integrals

The answer to this question is posted, but i don't understand what it means that as $b\to 0^+$ that this goes to infinity, and why is the integral split up in two?

[image: here's the answer,]

Answer (score 2):

Last term miss $\lim_{b \to 0+}$ - when you put it there you'll have answer:
$$\lim_{b \to 0^+}\left( \ln v|_{b}^{2} \right) = \lim_{b \to 0^+}\left( \ln 2 - \ln b \right) = \ln 2 + \infty= +\infty $$

Comment: not following. Put it where?

Comment: Added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A function is Rieman-integrable on a compact set $A$ if
$$
\int_{A}f < \infty
$$

Formally Riemann integral exists only on compact sets, so it's not well-defined if either the function, as in your case, or the interval (e.g. $x \to \infty$) is unbounded. Therefore, to extend Riemann integral to either case, the limit is replaced by some value, e.g. $\varepsilon>0$, as in your case. Such integral is known as an improper integral.
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{\varepsilon}^{b}\frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^{+}} (F(b) -F(\varepsilon))
$$
Again, in your case this limit doesn't exist (or equal to $\infty$), so the function is not Riemann-integrable.

EDIT concerning your interval of $[-2,2]$: note it contains a discontinuity at $0$. By construction, Riemann integral is a limit of upper and lower sums, and the value in each interval lies between upper ($\sup$) and lower ($\inf$) values of the function $(x_i <t <x_{i+1})$:
$$
\inf f(x^{\ast}_t)(x_{i+1} - x_i)\\
\sup f(x^{\ast}_t)(x_{i+1} - x_i)
$$
Obviously $ -\infty < \inf f(x^{\ast}_t) < \sup f(x^{\ast}_t) < \infty$, and if this condition is violated, Riemann integral doesn't exist in this interval.